# Finding all associated records of common child or parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Identity(id, super_identity_id)` and a table `Conversation(id, identity_id)`

Multiple identities can refer to the same `super_identity`.

Say I have `identity A`, I would like to get all `conversations`

1. who belongs to `A`
2. and who belongs to the `super_identity` of `A`
3. and who belongs to any `identity` who share the same `super_identity` as `A`

The best I have been able to do is

```
select 
    i.id,
    i.super_identity_id
from identities i 
left join identities ii on ii.super_identity_id = i.super_identity_id
where ii.id = 133
```

But the above does not respect `(2)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
i.id,
i.super_identity_id
from identities i 
inner join identities ii on ii.super_identity_id = i.super_identity_id and ii.id = 133
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I returns a bunch of `identities` without an associated `super_identity`

Comment: if you only want data that exists in both table A and table B, you shd use inner join. please see updated code @Tarlen

Comment: Say that the `identity` with `id = 133` has an `super_identity_id` of `120`, then the super identity is not returned in the result, which it should (see `(2)`).

Comment: i'm quite confused, could you please add sample data? @Tarlen

Comment: Please add explanation along with your code snippet.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Noted. @DimaSan